# XPath returns value in C# utility but not in Expression shape in Biztalk

Tags: c#, xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2013

In the XML message below I can get 'AccountNumber' using

```
//*[local-name()='AccountNumber']/text()
```

or

```
/*[local-name()='GetFullAxxAccountNoResponse']/*[local-name()='GetFullAxxAccountNoResult']/*[local-name()='FullAxxAccNo']/*[local-name()='FullAxxAccountNo']/*[local-name()='AccountNumber']
```

This works fine in a C# test app or in the Notepad++ XPath plugin, but it does not return anything when used in a BizTalk expression shape, can anyone help flesh this out? I have also tried including the namespace in the top level node but had no luck.

Expression shape code:

```
vAccount = xpath(mymessage.body, "either one of the xpath statements above")
```

Instance:

```xml
<GetFullAxxAccountNoResponse xmlns="http://temp.org/">
    <GetFullAxxAccountNoResult>
       <FullAxxAccNo>
           <FullAxxAccountNo>
               <AccountNumber>123456</AccountNumber>
           </FullAxxAccountNo>
       </FullxxAccNo>
    <SuccessFlag>success</SuccessFlag>
    <Message />
    </GetFullAxxAccountNoResult>
</GetFullAxxAccountNoResponse>
```

Comment: What's the code in your expression shape? how do you know it does not return anything?

Comment: Don't have it in front of me right now but from memory, vAccount = xpath(mymessage.body, "either one of the xpath statements above"). I know it's not returning as I'm checking the value of vAccount in the biztalk orchestration debugger.

Comment: I ac also see there is a value in that node to be extracted...

Comment: I am not sure if my memory is right, But try change  `xpath(mymessage.body, "//*[local-name()='AccountNumber']/text()")` to  `xpath(mymessage.body, "string(//*[local-name()='AccountNumber'])")` to see if it works. I am assuming this vAccount is a string in your orchestration

Comment: that did it thanks. If you want to put this in an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 2):

Those xPaths by themselves will return a Node.  To get the text content, you should use a format such as:

> xpath(myMessage, "string(//*[local-name()='SomeElement']/text())")

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using /text(). which returns a text node. you shall use string() function to converting the node to string.

so

```
xpath(mymessage.body, "string(//*[local-name()='AccountNumber'])")
```

shall work.

In addition. If you have your schema defined for this message in your biztalk application. promote this field as a distinguished fields in the schema will make your expression looks more clean. you can access this field like this:

```
vAcccount = mymessage.AccountNumber
```